# Specific word for walking from and to

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any specific word to describe walking the same path from one place to other. For e.g, 1 Km line, where someone walks from one end and turns back, goes to other end & Keeps repeating it.

Comment: For a shorter length (eg, walking back and forth in a room) it would be "pacing" -- "He paced back and forth while he waited."

Answer (score 2):

'to and fro' is good enough - http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/to-and-fro - in one direction and then in the opposite direction

Answer (score 2):

[Back and forth](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/back+and+forth) is another common expression:

> - in one direction and then the other repeatedly; from one place to another repeatedly.
>
>   - The tiger paced back and forth  in its cage.
> - if someone or something moves back and forth between two places, they move from one place to the other place again and again.
>
>   - Nurses went back and forth among the wounded, bringing food and medicine.

(TFD)

Answer (score 1):

You might say a person doing this is ***shuttling*** between points. A shuttle bus or shuttle flight is one that repeatedly retraces the same route

Comment: This is very much suitable to what I need.

Answer (score 0):

**PACER** *noun*: **1. one that paces**; *specifically* : a horse whose predominant gait is the pace.

> from Merriam-Webster Dictionary *online*

or,

> **PACE** *verb* gerund or present participle: ***pacing***
>
> walk at a steady and consistent speed, especially back and forth and as an expression of one's anxiety or annoyance.
>
> from **Google** [**link**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=pacing+definition&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: That's the wrong definition.

Comment: well, enlighten me then.

Comment: Start with the verb "pace".  Has nothing to do with gait.

Comment: @Hot Licks - all other answers, and your comment, describe a person's actions. I, on the other hand, answered OP's literal question, "describe a person ..."

Comment: Well, my question probably seems ambiguous. But, I didn't ask the word for a person.

Comment: My question title and description is somewhat mismatching. I'll edit it, so as not to cause any misunderstanding.

Comment: Yeah, I get that, but I believed that "pacer" also implies "pacing", so I left it at that. It's "all good", as they say. :-)

Comment: Thanks @Hot Licks, I amended as a result of your critique. Good looking-out!